# How do you programmatically create pages in a task

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I would like to be able to create pages programmatically in a task in 2.0.0. In 0.5.x there was an example for apostrophe-blog-2 which we used and extended from there.

The model layer is an `apostrophe-pieces` extension, which is displayed through an `apostrophe-pieces-pages`.

The `apostrophe-pieces-pages` page is parked and as such is always available.

More specifically I would like to:

1. Create Areas for Rich Text
2. Upload attachements using uploadfs and add them to a singleton area in the page
3. Be able to set or modify the slug, before or after the fact to the piece, during the task

Finally store the piece as published